# why am I inserting multiple spaces into my list

Tags: java, regex, list, parsing

I'm reading from a txt file, which contains a paragraph, and I'm parsing the words and inserting them into a list; however, I'm inserting spaces also. Somehow, my regex is do not seem to work every time encounters a comma or a dot because it adds a space... if someone could suggest a regex that could fix that? Thanks

```
public class Exercise225 {

    public static void main(String... args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String file = "words.txt";
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(file));
        String[] words = null;

        String line = "";
        List list = new ArrayList();

        while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
            line = inFile.nextLine();
            words = line.split("[\n|\r|\t| |,|.|)|(|-|\"|!]");

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                list.add(words[i].toLowerCase());                   
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(list);

        System.out.println(list.size());

        Iterator listItr = list.iterator();

        while (listItr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(listItr.next());
        }

        inFile.close();

    }    
}
```

Comment: I'd think you would have to escape the "." in your regex?

Comment: I think you should start with escaping '.' and '-' -- these are special characters in Regex.

Comment: The dot does not need to be escaped. It's not special inside a character class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of splitting on exactly one separator you can split on one *or more* separators using the `+` quantifier. Also you do not need to use a pipe in a character class.

```
String regex = "[\n\r\t ,.)(\"!-]+";
words = line.split(regex);
```

Comment: But what about the Line starts with Empty Chars?

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\s+` for space in your regex used for splitting. This will match one or more white spaces during the split.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this below change will get you the expected result

```
       String regEx = "[\n|\r|\t| |,|.|)|(|-|\"|!]";                
       line = inFile.nextLine().replaceAll(regEx+"^", "");          
       if(line.length()<=0)continue;                                
       words = line.split(regEx+"+");
```